# Cancel array of Tasks with RetryOptions using Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, task-parallel-library, azure-durable-functions

I'm using Azure Functions V4. In an orchestration (`MyCustomOrchestration`) I do a fan-out and call an `ActivityTriggered`-function (`HandleIdFunction`). The fan-out will usually contain around 20 tasks. The `HandleIdFunction` is called with a `RetryOptions` and can throw different exceptions. The retry should retry if any exception is thrown, except for `MyCustomError`. If `MyCustomError` is thrown all tasks should be aborted and stop retrying, no matter what exception they may throw. I don't seem to get it to work. The retries keep retrying.

I could not find a way to pass a `CancellationToken`. And if I set a variable in `Handle` it will be reset during replay.

Complete reproducable example below:

```
public class MyCustomError : Exception
{

}

public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
          [DurableClient] IDurableClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var result = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(MyCustomOrchestration));
        return new OkObjectResult(result);
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(HandleIdFunction))]
    public static async Task HandleIdFunction([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
    {
        var input = context.GetInput<int>();
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(HandleIdFunction)} - {input}.");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        // Fake errors.
        if (input == 10)
            throw new MyCustomError();
        if (input % 2 == 0)
            throw new Exception();
    }

        [FunctionName(nameof(MyCustomOrchestration))]
    public static async Task MyCustomOrchestration([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var parallelTasks = new List<Task<Guid>>();

        var retryOptions = new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 30)
        {
            BackoffCoefficient = 1.85,
            MaxRetryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            RetryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            Handle = exception =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Retry handled called");
                return (exception.InnerException is not MyCustomError);
            }
        };

        int[] idBatch = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < idBatch.Length; i++)
        {
            var id = idBatch[i];
            Task<Guid> task = context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync<Guid>(nameof(HandleIdFunction), retryOptions, id);
            parallelTasks.Add(task);
        }

        Guid[] result = null;

        try
        {
            result = await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex.InnerException is MyCustomError)
        {
            // Custom handling.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Custom handling.
        }
    }
}
```